# SQL Server 2012 compatibility with Microsoft Server 2016

Tags: sql-server-2012, windows-server

This is just a really simple question before I steam roller ahead
and wreck everything.

I have ordered a server that will have Windows Server 2016 installed
however I have now realized that the tools we will be using only support
SQL Server 2012.

I'm not sure but I think Windows Server and SQL Server are completely
separate entities so would it still be OK for me to install
SQL Server 2012 on a Windows Server 2016 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, OS (Windows Server) and database (SQL Server) are separate entities. So the only question is compatibility between those two products.
I'm guessing it was tested and should be ok, but at this moment SQL Server 2012 doesn't have Windows Server 2016 listed (and won't have, at least not till September):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Best thing You can do is download latest Technical Preview and test it with SQL Server 2012 in Your environment:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-technical-preview

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful, I will download Oracle Virtual Box and try to install the Windows Server 2016 first

Comment: Just to confirm SQL Server 2012 works fine with W/S 2016 in general terms. I'm currently running a lot dev machines on this configuration as a test.

Comment: @Molenpad I would still put it through some testing process, just to check if there are any specific local issues, either hardware related or caused by 3rd party software.

Comment: Yep, that's why I said 'in general terms'